# Service seems recreated but isnt

Tags: android, service

I have serivce in its own process, activity (in another process) is finished and I stop the service and in logcat I see onDestroy (in serivce) is called. Then I open the app again and I see onCreate(in serivce) is called. My problem is, the service acts like it was never destroyed, even objects in it are kept. I am calling stopForeground in onDestroy too. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

use below code for your service in manifest file. It will call the ondestroy and remove the app from recent app list.

```
<service android:name="service" android:stopWithTask="true"/>
```